# What is Python's default exit code?

Tags: python, exit-code

Assuming your script doesn't exit due to any kind of failure (exception, syntax error) and the script doesn't exit due to `sys.exit()` or `os._exit()`, how does Python figure out what exit code to exit with?

It seems to be 0, which makes sense since it indicates no-error on *nix systems.  However, will that always be the case that it exits with 0 (except for the cases above)?  Surprisingly after quite a bit of online searching, I couldn't find anything which explicitly said that it would exit with 0 unless otherwise specified.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`sys.exit` documents a default exit status of `0`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exit), and [`os._exit`'s docs specify a UNIX-like OS constant for "normal" exit status, `os.EX_OK`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.EX_OK), but there is no documented guarantee I can find for the exit status in general.

Aside from that, the best I can give you is that in CPython, the `python` executable (including `python.exe`/`pythonw.exe` on Windows) is implemented in `python.c` by calling [`Py_Main`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/veryhigh.html#c.Py_Main) and returning whatever it returns; per the documented guarantees on `Py_Main`, the exit status is:

> `0` if the interpreter exits normally (i.e., without an exception), `1` if the interpreter exits due to an exception, or `2` if the parameter list does not represent a valid Python command line.
>
> Note that if an otherwise unhandled `SystemExit` is raised, this function will not return `1`, but exit the process, as long as `Py_InspectFlag` is not set.

so this implies that simply running off the end of the `__main__` module without an active exception should always return `0` for CPython, though alternate interpreters are not technically *required* to do the same.

This tracks with [the implied exit status rules expected of most applications](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html); while nothing explicitly says Python has to follow those rules, it would be extremely unusual for a tool that grew up in the command line UNIX-like world to violate those conventions.

Comment: Thanks ShadowRanger.  Martin Broadhurst's answer (tracing more through the code) confirms the Py_Main documentation.

Answer (score 8):

If you look at the [cpython source code](https://github.com/python/cpython):

1. `main()` in `Programs/python.c` returns the return value of `Py_Main()`
2. `Py_Main()` in `Modules/main.c` returns the return value of `run_file()`
3. `run_file()`, also in `Modules/main.c` returns `0` unless `PyRun_AnyFileExFlags()` returns non-zero
4. `PyRun_AnyFileExFlags()` in `Python/pythonrun.c` will `exit()` in
   the event of a `SystemExit` exception and so will not return if the
   script sets an exit code. It will only return non-zero if there
   is an internal error.

So the return value of `run_file()` is what makes the default exit code of a script `0`.

Answer (score 1):

Exiting with 0 predates Python by a long time, it is part of the [POSIX standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status#POSIX). All well-behaved programs indicate a successful exit with 0.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that 0 has long been a *nix standard meaning no-error.  I just want to see it in writing (or in Python source code) that it always uses 0 if there were no exceptions, errors or explicit requests to exit

Answer (score 1):

Python's default exit code is 0. This is documented here https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.SystemExit

However, the exit code will be whatever the is specified in the `exit()` or `quit()` functions. So, if you are using a script, you should always check within the script or script documentation what that particular script will return. For example: you could launch python in a terminal, and just type `quit(1)` and it exits with return code of 1 even though there are no errors.

Comment: This isn't quite right because a `SystemExit` is not raised if the script doesn't call `sys.exit()`.